# Can I play online multiplayer with another friend in splitscreen?

Tags: uncharted-3

I have a friend I play co-op/competitive multiplayer with, and another I sometimes do local splitscreen multiplayer with. I would really like to be able to have the two of us locally in splitscreen connect with my friend over the internet - is this possible?

From what I've seen the 'splitscreen' and 'online' options are separate so I'm not sure how to go about this. Would creating a local splitscreen game and then inviting my online friend work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can play split-screen and online at the same time, just choose the *Multiplayer* option in the main menu and choose *Play Online*, when the online finishes loading, choose *Splitscreen* on the menu on the left and choose a profile for your buddy, he'll join your party and you'll be able to invite your third friend and play CO-OP.